# How to create a queryset to filter jsonb fields with __ in key name

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have a jsonb field in one of my django model. There are few key value pairs in this json in table with __ in key name. Eg json:

```
data: {'base_cover__tenure': 2,
 'base_cover__variant': '125 Z',
}
```

How can I create a queryset to filter on these fields?
I have tried this  `MyModel.objects.filter(data__base_cover__tenure__gte=1)`, which obviously doesn't work.